# Table td set to colspan 1, still takes 2 column spaces

Tags: html, css, html-table

Title basically explains everything. My problem is that `td` (which I even gave a `colspan="1"`), still takes 2 column spaces. What am I missing?

[image]

Here is code snippet if you want to copy it over:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="group_name">Group Name</td>
    <td class="date">1536313586</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="1"><img class="avi" src="default.png"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="user_name">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="message">6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Edit

Here is a picture of how I want it to look; it's working now, but I fixed it with div's and CSS, though I would still prefer it be done with tables:

[image]

Comment: It not seems to take 2 columns spaces due it "share" the row with the column name.

Comment: how do i work around it? I want the name to take 2 column spaces and img tag only take 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to keep the table column structure properly, Try this

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="group_name">Group Name</td>
    <td class="date">1536313586</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="1"><img class="avi" src="default.png"> . </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="user_name">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="message">6</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, tho this doesn't seem to solve it. the image still takes 2 column spaces :(

Comment: I have updated the snippet code, please check it, I hope it will help you, I finally find another solutions, if you need I will share with you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution i see to this problem (i'm not satisfied):

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="group_name">Group Name 1536313586</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td rowspan="2"><img class="avi" src="default.png"></td>
 <td class="user_name">Nameasdasdasdadsadsadsdsa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="message">6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `i'm not satisfied`. Why not?

Comment: I didn't want the date and the group name in the same cell. The way that this will work is, i have to put a `span` around the date (`1536313586`), and add a `float: right` to it. It works; just feels like a hack to me when i should be able to do it with `colspan` and `rowspan` (unless i misunderstood the purpose of those)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how it should looks eventually. Can you draw the result you want? Maybe I could help with it.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It now shows an image of how i want it to work with all the edge cases in the picture.

Comment: From the image I can say that a table structure is not fit to your case because the "columns" in "row" 1 and "row" 2 have not the same width. So there is not point to use `table`.

Comment: Ohhh. I see. It makes sense actually. I just thought i'd use tables to make sure the content doesn't overflow, but i guess you got a better point. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Sure :) Another and more important point, `table`s are week when it comes to responsive design so, my recommendation is: don't use for layout at all. For layout you have [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)